# Airflow MySql Aborted connection

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We're seeing a lot of connection warnings as well with **Airflow 1.10.9 and Mariadb: 10.4.15**. I saw this post - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4848 but it doesn't give any specific answers.

```
2021-10-11 16:48:03 63580 [Warning] Aborted connection 63580 to db: 'airflow' user: 'blabla' host: 'airflow-scheduler-prod-64d6cf8879-gb4lz.airflow-scheduler-pr' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-11 16:48:03 63578 [Warning] Aborted connection 63578 to db: 'airflow' user: 'blabla' host: 'airflow-scheduler-prod-64d6cf8879-gb4lz.airflow-scheduler-pr' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-10-11 16:48:03 63581 [Warning] Aborted connection 63581 to db: 'airflow' user: 'blabla' host: 'airflow-scheduler-prod-64d6cf8879-gb4lz.airflow-scheduler-pr' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but this may be related to https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11543 which was fixed by https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12046 and released in Airflow 2. I don't think you will find a proper solution for this other than upgrade your Airflow version. To point out that you are running on Mariadb which isn't officially supported. In the documentation it is mentioned https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/prerequisites.html "MariaDB is not tested/recommended."